# Custom taxonomy rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress

Hello i want to change the default WordPress categories url i tried but i don't know how to do it
can you guys please help me with that..

This is my admin URL of default post category here post type=post

```
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category
```

example of my categories list
cloths, shirt, goggles etc...

suppose current my fronted link for taxonomy url is like

```
example.com/shirt
example.com/cloths
example.com/goggles
```

but i want to modify it... like below

```
example.com/ethic/shirt
example.com/ethic/cloths
example.com/ethic/goggles
```

And post Url must be followed same as below

```
example.com/res-full-shirt
example.com/blackfull-goggles
```

Comment: Look here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44596

Comment: Thanx but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think, these permalink settings will do the job.

[image: Permalink Settings]

Comment: Hii thank for your ans but it still showing old slug